# SWT DataBinding for DateTime

Tags: data-binding, swt, rcp

I want to display a `java.util.Date` using two `DateTime` controls - one displaying the date and one the time.

I try to use databinding here to set the values entered in the controls. I try to bind the controls to the date as follows:

```java
IObservableValue getPostponeDateDayObserveValue = SWTObservables.observeSelection(getPostponeDate());
IObservableValue getPostponeTargetDateDateObserveValue = PojoObservables.observeValue(this, "postponeTargetDate");
bindingContext.bindValue(getPostponeDateDayObserveValue, getPostponeTargetDateDateObserveValue, null, null);
    //
IObservableValue getPostponeTimeSecondsObserveValue = SWTObservables.observeSelection(getPostponeTime());
IObservableValue postponeTargetDateSecondsObserveValue = PojoObservables.observeValue(this, "postponeTargetDate");
bindingContext.bindValue(getPostponeTimeSecondsObserveValue, postponeTargetDateSecondsObserveValue, null, null);
```

What happens here is that the date corries the correct date or the correct time depending on which control was changed later. Is there a possibility to bind two datetime controls (one for date one for time) to the same date.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

just overlooked the class that helps here:
[DateAndTimeObservableValue](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/value/DateAndTimeObservableValue.html)